# Custom Navigation Bar Android - Quarter Screen Height and Transparent Background

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I want to know how to go about building this type of ui. I have a bottom navigation bar in my app and when the add button is clicked I want to show an arc menu like below while maintaining the previously inflated view at the remainder of the screen height.

Image example:
[image]

I have used fragments to implement the default way of bottom navigation but how do I adapt it to look like this. The `BottomNavigationView` widget does not have support for partial rendering of views. Is there a library that supports this or a custom way to do this? Thanks.

EDIT:
This is my current implementation using fragment transactions, fragments and default bottom nav widget:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar toolbar;
private BottomNavigationView bottomNav;

private Fragment fragment;
private FragmentTransaction transaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();

}

private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragHolder, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}

private void init() {
    bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottomNav);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    fragment = new HomeFragment();
    switchFragment(fragment);

    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_notifications:
            fragment = new AlertsFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_add:
            //fragment = new AddFragment();
            //switchFragment(fragment);
            //return true;
            This is where I want to load the curved menu/dialog and ideally the previous screen from Activity Stack or Fragment BackStack will be visible on top and this screen only takes up 20-25% of screen height
        case R.id.nav_messages:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: You could use a dialog, since it will automatically create the background you're looking for, and can be dismissed by clicking outside of the view.

Comment: I have used fragments. Can you post sample code pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a complete example, but hopefully it can give you an idea of what you could do.

This uses a custom BottomSheetDialog, and the perk with using a dialog is that it's easily dismissed with the back button or clicking outside the view.

### TestDialog.java

```
public class TestDialog extends BottomSheetDialog
{
    private Context _context;

    public TestDialog(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this._context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        Window window = getWindow();
        if (window != null)
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
    }
}
```

### R.layout.test_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/curve"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="New Session"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Enroll Player"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="New Batch"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### @drawable/curve

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="-80dp"
        android:left="-100dp"
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

### Showing dialog

```
TestDialog dialog = new TestDialog(MainActivity.this);
tdialog.show();

//This is done in order to make dialog width match the screen width
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

### What to do now

There are two things you have left to implement now if you decide to go down this path. First would be to make sure that the dialog window itself does not have a background, right now it's not fully transparent and second thing would be to make sure it does not cover your `BottomNavigationView`

### Example how to show the dialog in your case

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_notifications:
            fragment = new AlertsFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_add:
            //Show the dialog
            TestDialog dialog = new TestDialog(MainActivity.this);
            tdialog.show();

            //This is done in order to make dialog width match the screen width
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        case R.id.nav_messages:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            switchFragment(fragment);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I'll check this example out and inform you. How do I inflate this in my bottom navigation view? In my code, I have used fragment transactions in onNavigationListener method.

Comment: Doing it this way you won't do anything with your `BottomNavigationView` but instead just having the dialog overlaying the current view.

Comment: I am asking where do I have to call this class to render the view. Let me edit the question

Comment: Your current activity where you are hosting the `BottomNavigationView` and Fragments :)

Comment: I edited my answer to include how you can show it in your example

Comment: Just tested it. It works in a way that the curve from drawable is not shown and it is animated with a little margin at the bottom and also the background view shown is that of the next fragment after add, so in a way the nav listener is trying to skip this, I think

Comment: If we can fix the curve, animation and margin that will be amazing. Either way I am going to accept your answer. Your effort is well appreciated. Thank you svm sir